# Python - Avoid duplicate entries scraping reddit images

Tags: python, python-3.x, praw

I am new to python and trying to write a script. I am able to get a list of URLs and then writing them to a file. I'll figure out how to download them later.

At this point, my concern is:

1. How do I ensure that the URLs (or items in the list) that I already have aren't scraped again?
2. Is it actually a good approach to add the URLs to list because in no time there would be hundreds / thousands of them OR do I just want to maintain a text file with the URLs?

Here's the code that I have.

```
import praw
import json

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='myy-client',
                     client_secret='my-secret',
                     user_agent='my-user-agent')

my_sub = reddit.subreddit('earthporn')
imagesList = []
badContent = "comments"

#myfile = open('images.txt', 'w')
for i in my_sub.new():
    imagesList.append(i.url)
    #myfile.write(i.url + " \n")
#myfile.close()

if badContent in imagesList:
    imagesList.remove()

print(imagesList)
```

Note that the "write to file" lines are actually commented out. I was just experimenting with them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save unique URL you should use `set` instead of `list`.

You could use a json file to save all the data and then iterate it like a generator or something that would't use a lot of your ram memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a basic cache using JSON. If you're using a dict, you can test if the file was previously downloaded. One way is to store metadata as a dict, saved to JSON. Then the downloaded file is a separate blob.

Imagine you have:

```
cache = {
    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57105974/python-avoid-duplicate-entries-scraping-reddit-images": {
        "download_date": "2018/09/19 15:55:09",
        "local_file": "2018 09 19 - 15 55 09 866446.html",
    },
    "http://www.example.org/cat.jpg": {
        "download_date": "2018/09/19 15:55:09",
        "local_file": "2018 09 19 - 15 55 09 866446.jpg",
    }
}
```

You can test for existence using `if url in cache`

```
import datetime
import os
import json

STR_DATE_FORMAT_MICROSECONDS = '%Y %m %d - %H %M %S %f' # the specifice datetime I used

def download(url):
    # downloads binary blob. saves to /cached/foo.ext
    data = actually_download(url)    
    now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(STR_DATE_FORMAT_SECONDS)

    filepath = "{datetime}{ext}".format(
        datetime=now,
        ext=ext_type,
    )

    path = os.path.join("cached", filepath)

    # now write `data` to `path`

    return {
        'download_date': now,
        'local_file': filepath,
    }

def request_cached(cache, url):
    if url not in cache:
        cache[url] = download(url)

    return cache[url]


def main():

    with open("cache.json", mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        cache = json.load(f)

    url = # ... 
    request_cached(cache, url)

    # save
    with open("cache.json", mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(cache, f, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

In the future you can use `download_date` to decide if the cache is still good.